# Hex Editing Recalculate checksum

Tags: hex, edit

I am trying to edit a proprietary file, it is a .pin file for pinpoint graphics, if you've heard of it +10 for you. I need to edit it in a hex environment (e.g, HexEdit) to change a file path from program files to program files (x86) for upgrade purposes. I am able to do so if the length of the path does not change however adding those 6 bytes changes it obviously. The only other way to change this path is to load it into our software and change it, there are thousands of these files and I reallllly don't want to spend days on that.

I looked into recalculating checksums and patching it in however I can't find material in depth enough for me, I was hoping somebody here could give me a hand.

Comment: you lost me in "I need to edit it in a hex environment (e.g, HexEdit) to change a file path from program files to program files (x86) for upgrade purposes."

Comment: the file needs to be edited in hex workshop or equivalent, it could be edited in notepad but i figured it would be clearer if i stated that instead, clearly not, i apologize

Comment: no yeah.. that part I get.. (sort of) but... the file that is in hex, has a file path that you wanna change? is that it?

Comment: yes, precisely, again I apologize, this is not my normal field of expertise, trying to learn on the job so I don't have to spend endless hours doing this in the future

Comment: sorry, i should say this, the file format is kind of part executable, but not really, i tried applying some structures to it in hex workshop to see if it had any format but it doesnt pick it up, it's kind of an obsolete piece of software that creates the file

Comment: Then, I imagine that those .pin files have the path and other stuff and also a checksum, and if you change the path, the checksum becomes invalid?

Comment: It sounds like it would take longer to open each file and try to hack it in a hex editor than it would to open each file and resave it in the software, no?  Without knowing the file format, you are probably asking for trouble with corrupted files.

Comment: that's what i'm assuming, but I don't know what checksum algorithm they are using nor where it would be stored/validated.

Comment: it takes about 3-4 minutes per file * about 5000 files to change the path, i know the paths to change, i have a python script that successfully overwrites the bytes, all i'd have to do is let that script run

Comment: Does the original software offer any kind of a macro capability where you can script this?  Alternatively, would it be possible to use some kind of a UI testing tool to manipulate the software UI so that you can script the process of changing the file path and saving the file?

Comment: no it doesn't :( it's awful software. what kind of UI testing tool did you have in mind that may be more viable

Comment: Could you possibly use the 8.3 path (i.e `PROGRA~2`) for `Program Files` and pad the empty space with null characters? You can find the 8.3 path like this: `dir C:\Prog* /X /AD`

Comment: I did not have specific one in mind; I honestly have not done a lot with that kind of thing, but I know they exist.  Usually they are used in software development shops to write automated tests for the software so that Quality Assurance personnel don't have to manually carry out repetitive tests from build to build.  The tester app has the capability to click buttons, fill in text fields, simulate mouse moves etc.  There is a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools).  It may be an alternative approach to trying to hack the file.

Comment: Simon, I'll give that a shot now, that would be brilliant, Brian after you mentioned it I felt dumb for not considering it. That may work good as this is all mfc win32 stuff

Comment: Simons idea did the trick, thanks guys I really appreciate it, and so did my future diabetes if I had to manually do all these files

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. Just FYI, if you want people to be notified when you reply to comments, you need to quote their name, i.e. @user2242772.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie You should write up your idea as an answer.  I have to admit it was quite clever and you deserve some credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to change the path length when trying to replace `Program Files` with `Program Files (x86)`, I'd suggest you try using the [8.3 path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) (i.e `PROGRA~2`), then pad the empty space with null characters.

You can find the 8.3 path like this:

```
dir %systemdrive%\Prog* /X /AD
```